# gulp creates src directory structure in dist

Tags: gulp, tsconfig

I got the following `gulp` tasks,

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');
const typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const print = require('gulp-print');

// clean the contents of the distribution directory
gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return del('dist/**/*');
});

// TypeScript compile
gulp.task('compile', ['clean'], function () {
  return gulp
    .src(tscConfig.files)
    .pipe(print(function (filepath) {
      return 'Processing ' + filepath + '...';
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['compile']);
gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

and a directory structure

```
|
+- dist
|
+- src 
|   |
|   +- app
|   |   |
|   |   + - example.ts
```

Now if I run `gulp build` I get another `app/src` inside `dist`, that is

```
|
+- dist
|   |
|   + - app
|        |
|        + - src 
|             |
|             + - app
|                  |
|                  + - example.js
|                  + - example.js.map
+- src 
|   |
|   +- app
|   |   |
|   |   + - example.ts
```

which is not what I want. How can I tell gulp to instead create the following directory structure?

```
|
+- dist
|   |
|   + - app
|        |
|        + - example.js
|        + - example.js.map 
|
+- src 
|   |
|   +- app
|   |   |
|   |   + - example.ts
```

Do I need `gulp-replace` for that or is there another option?

EDIT: `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist/app",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "files": [
        "src/app/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to using `gulp-rename`, if anyone can think of a better solution I'm eager to hear it.

```
gulp.task('compile', function () {
  return gulp
    .src(tscConfig.files)
    .pipe(print(function (filepath) {
      return 'Processing ' + filepath + '...';
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
      if (path.dirname === 'src\\app') {
        path.dirname = '';
      } else {
        path.dirname = path.dirname.replace('src\\app\\', '');
      }
    }))
    .pipe(print(function (filepath) {
      return 'Generated file: ' + filepath;
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app'));
});
```